# How to fix an image over the div?

Tags: html, css, image, overlay, absolute

http://estreetusa.us/piechart/
i want to fix the center image, i.e 24 hours written on it, please suggesst.
back is css for background-image and fish is css for overlaid image ..
relative;

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Alter the left and top value to your preference.

Comment: Give us your code or create a Codepen/JS Fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options in this case.

You can set left to 50% and then center it by setting the margin-left to -98px (half the elements width). Don't forget to give it's parent position: relative;

```
.fish {
    background-image: url("24.png");
    width: 196px;
    height: 196px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 426px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -98px;
}
```

OR you can put 24.png in a img element and set it's display to inline or inline-block. Then you give the parent text-align: center.

If the content above the clock doesnt change (in height), I would go for the first option. Otherwise go for the second.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your fish class to this:

```
.fish {
   background-image: url(24.png);
   width: 196px;
   height: 196px;
   position: relative;
   margin: -295px auto;
   right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule in your css file:

```
.fish{
    margin-left:3.5%;
}
```

Comment: it'll just work on your screen size maybe, indeed you should get center of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Firt add `position: relative`to the `section` element that contains both elements,

Then put the `fish` DIV inside the `back` DIV (making fish's position depend on back) and alter the top and left settings accordingly (approximat setting: top: 96px; left: 471px;)

Answer (score 0):

use this css for your current HTML.

```
background-image: url(24.png);
width: 196px;
height: 196px;
position: relative;
top: -300px;
```

for the above css top margin have to adjust for device specific

to make image  perfectly in center you have to nested the image into the canvas 
and then apply below css

```
background-image: url(24.png);
width: 196px;
height: 196px;
position: relative;
```